# What easy-to-use software can I use for streaming a meeting?

Tags: audio, video-conferencing

So, I got the "honour" to setup a possibility for my dads office to stream meetings they have, so members who live a bit farther don't have to travel there (it's mostly volunteers, so you can't force them to come).

What they want to do is to setup a video and audio feed of the medium sized conference room and let the people that can't come in person participate in their discussion rounds. Of course most of them aren't IT aficionados, so the software has to be very easy to use.

What I thought of would be to buy a good webcam and a seperate microphone that can be set in the middle of the table to capture all of the peoples voices, as I fear the webcams integrated microfone will not work properly with so many people.

However, wouldn't I get a double audio signal from both the webcam and the microfone? Or do most drivers offer you the option to disable the integrated micro? I really need good audio here.

My first option would have been to use Google Hangouts, 1 member of the chat is the office, and all the others (up to 10, I believe?) are single persons. However, I don't have any experience with Hangouts, so I don't know the restrictions, video quality, etc..

Thanks in advance for any useful tips.